# 0..n result transformation with offset and limit produces inaccurate results

Tags: java, postgresql, querydsl

I've searched for proper answer but unfortunately did't find any working solution for QueryDsl SQL module.
I'm trying to fetch simple entities with 0..n relation using left join on custom property:

```java
class Parent {
    private Long id;
    private String uuid;
    private Set<Child> children;
}

class Child {
    private Long id;
    private String uuidRef;
}
```

To be able to populate dto's I'm transforming results as follows:

```java
queryFactory().from(qParent)
    .leftJoin(qChild).on(qParent.uuid.eq(qChild.uuidRef))
    .where(...)
    .transform(GroupBy.groupBy(qParent.id).list(parentQBean))
```

There are Parent rows having multiple Child relations.
Everything works fine unless I add additional limit and offset to the query for pagination pupropses. Let's day I want first 20 results so I'm adding .offset(0).limit(20).

In db there are 2 parent records having 2 child rows each. After transformig/grouping I only get 18 rows/objects as a result. I'm aware that this is due to SQL query itself as it returns left joined rows as separate result row and transforming is done in memory, but I wonder if this is possible to handle on SQL module somehow. I don't want to use JPA as this is rather small project with only few tables and JPA/Hibernate would be overkill. SQL module is perfect for this :)

Using QueryDsl SQL 4.2.1 with PostgreSQL 11.2

Answer (score 0):

I'd say JPA wouldn't handle that "correctly" either, at least not when trying to fetch the parents and their children in one go. As you've already noted the problem is that offset and limit are applied to the result and if a parent has multiple children the join can cause less parents to be loaded (or even only one parent with just a part of its children if there are many). You'd thus have to apply the offset and limit to something that represents a parent per row.

You could try something like this (I don't know QueryDsl so I'll just use pseudo-SQL):

```
select ... from parent p join children c on ...
   where p.id in ( select distinct id from parent order by whatever offset x limit y )
```

So what you'll want to do is determine the ids of the 20 parents in a subquery and then load those parents along with their chilren which might result in more than 20 result rows (22 in your case if 2 parents have 2 children and the other 18 just have 1 at most).